Adding Active Directory to Admin group
I have an Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 joined to my Active Directory Domain.
I also created a Domain Group from which the members have sudo permissions (configured through visudo).  This works as expected and when opening a Terminal, I have sudo privileges with my domain user.
However, my user is not a member of the Administrators group, which means that I always get a prompt to enter the credentials of a local admin in Gnome, when performing (system) changes.
Like for mapping a USB stick to the desktop => prompt.  How to add domain users / groups to Ubuntu Administrators?
